# Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias:

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i am using spatie query builder and for 2 filters i try to use 2 scopes that contains joins like below :

```
public function scopeFilterPrice(Builder $query,  $start_price,$end_price): Builder
    {
        $data = $query->leftjoin('accommodation_rooms','accommodation_rooms.id','=','accommodations.id')
            ->leftjoin('room_pricing_histories','room_pricing_histories.id','=','accommodation_rooms.id')
            ->where('sales_price', '>', $start_price)
            ->where('sales_price', '<', $end_price);
        ;
        return $data;
    }
    public function scopeFilterDate(Builder $query,$from_date,$to_date): Builder{

        $data = $query->leftjoin('accommodation_rooms','accommodation_rooms.id','=','accommodations.id')
            ->Join('room_capacity_histories','room_capacity_histories.id','=','accommodation_rooms.id')
        ->whereDate('from_date', '>', $from_date)
        ->whereDate('to_date', '<', $to_date);
//        $data = $query->whereHas('accommodationRooms.roomCapacityHistory', function (Builder $q) use ($from_date, $to_date) {
        return $data;
```

when i run each of them individually its fine but when i active 2 filters together it gives me the below error :

```
 "message": "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'accommodation_rooms' (SQL: select * from `accommodations` left join `accommodation_rooms` on `accommodation_rooms`.`id` = `accommodations`.`id` left join `room_pricing_histories` on `room_pricing_histories`.`id` = `accommodation_rooms`.`id` left join `accommodation_rooms` on `accommodation_rooms`.`id` = `accommodations`.`id` inner join `room_capacity_histories` on `room_capacity_histories`.`id` = `accommodation_rooms`.`id` where `sales_price` > 1 and `sales_price` < 9999999 and date(`from_date`) > 2019-05-22 and date(`to_date`) < 2029-10-22 and `city_id` = 329)",
    "code": "42000",
    "status_code": 500,
```

any advice how can i do that ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using model query scopes and your query should look like this:

```php
SomeModel::query()
    ...
    ->filterDate($date_from, $date_to)
    ->filterPrice($price_from, $price_to)
    ...
```

In query scopes you are joining on `accommodation_rooms` table again and again. That's why it throws a MySQL exception.

Solution 1: make join scope and then use it once. Delete accommodation_rooms join in your scopes.

```php
...
public function scopeJoinRooms(Builder $query): Builder{
    return $query->leftjoin('accommodation_rooms','accommodation_rooms.id','=','accommodations.id');
}
...
// Query Should look like this
SomeModel::query()
    ...
    ->joinRooms()
    ->filterDate($date_from, $date_to)
    ->filterPrice($price_from, $price_to)
    ...
```

Solution 2: check if join exists in every scope before join (I don't recommend this way).

```php
...

public function scopeFilterPrice(Builder $query,  $start_price,$end_price): Builder
{
    $data = $query
        ->when(! (collect($query->getQuery()->joins)->pluck('table')->contains('accommodation_rooms')), function($q){
            return $q->leftjoin('accommodation_rooms','accommodation_rooms.id','=','accommodations.id');
        })
        ->leftjoin('room_pricing_histories','room_pricing_histories.id','=','accommodation_rooms.id')
        ->where('sales_price', '>', $start_price)
        ->where('sales_price', '<', $end_price);

    return $data;
}

public function scopeFilterDate(Builder $query,$from_date,$to_date): Builder{

    $data = $query->when(! (collect($query->getQuery()->joins)->pluck('table')->contains('accommodation_rooms')), function($q){
            return $q->leftjoin('accommodation_rooms','accommodation_rooms.id','=','accommodations.id');
        })
        ->Join('room_capacity_histories','room_capacity_histories.id','=','accommodation_rooms.id')
        ->whereDate('from_date', '>', $from_date)
        ->whereDate('to_date', '<', $to_date);

    return $data;
}
...
// Query Should look like this
SomeModel::query()
    ...
    ->filterDate($date_from, $date_to)
    ->filterPrice($price_from, $price_to)
    ...
```